# How do I show a progress window?

Tags: unity, window

I need to test something with Ubuntu's copy progress window. But I don't want to copy some big files to have it stay for the period of test. How can I have a demo Copy progress dialog without copying anything?

I'm on Unity, Ubuntu 16.04.

It seems newer nautilus included in Xenial doesn't even show a copy window. But I'm not asking specifically for nautilus. Anything generic which is a progress dialog will do the job.

Comment: Voting it unclear without asking any clarification in comment?

Comment: There's nothing unclear about this question. In a situation like this it would be appropriate if whoever voted it unclear posted a comment giving an  explanation of what was considered to be unclear.

Comment: @karel perhaps you should read the discussion under the answer

Comment: @muru I don't know if it's you who voted. But regarding your _unclear_ comment, you only edited the title, which indicates you had only problem with the title. But a user should read both title and description. If title is misleading you can always read the description + you have the option of commenting under question

Comment: @Anwar your original question was clear (you wanted the copy dialogue) but your answer made it unclear. I am not the only person who commented there, and I see no reason why I should comment both on the question and the answer when you're the one who posted both.

Comment: And I don't see how my editing your question indicates *I* was the only one confused.

Comment: @muru I think, I said in a comment under the answer that i wrote the answer as a _close_ to the solution. Not the exact thing. So, that should not make the answer _unclear_. And I didn't say _You_ was the only one. You originally commented as unclear and you editing says it was only the title that was unclear (from your edit), I only said that.

Comment: @muru And Thank you for the downvote. That wasn't unexpected from you

Comment: @Anwar you're most welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that `zenity` can do this. Using this command seems to be sufficient

```
zenity --progress --auto-close --time-remaining --pulsate --text="Copying 2 of 4 files"
```

That brings a progress dialog window like this

[image: progress window]

Comment: If that's really your answer, I don't understand your question. Why did you need this, exactly?

Comment: @muru You didn't understand if this is an answer or why I needed this?

Comment: Both. That's not a copy window, and nautilus' copy progress display is nothing like zenity's.

Comment: @muru This is not an exact answer I know, but this is most close I found. I needed a copy progress dialog (not specific to nautilus as I mentioned in the question) and it is a progress dialog. I needed this to set a rule based on window type. I waited more than 1 month and no one answered. A question with a close answer is better than leaving it unanswered imo. That's why I wrote this

Comment: Originally you've asked for nautilus copy dialog, so I think that explains why there was no answer for a while - simply because it is impossible to do with Nautilus. You might want to reword your question that you're open to alternative solutions :) just FYI

Comment: @Serg I thought I wrote about a "generic progress dialog" already (it was edited on Sep 9). I've edited it again. Is it better now? If you want to answer, please do.

Comment: Also Gtk has the option. Quite simple to write a basic sample.

Comment: @JacobVlijm well...yes it can be quite simple and easy. But the question was left unanswered.